# how to perform drag operation on widget with Gesturedetector flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

I want to drag and drop my custom widget with gesture detector. It is showing x- direction and y- direction values but not dragging to anywhere on screen.

Here is my code:

layoutpage:

```
SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: Stack(
                      children: _layoutProvider.tables
                          .map(
                            (SectionTable sTable) => Positioned(
                              top: sTable.top,
                              left: sTable.left,
                              child: LayoutWidget(
                                width: sTable.width,
                                height: sTable.height,
                                type: sTable.type.index,
                                name: sTable.name,
                                left: sTable.left,
                                top: sTable.top,
                                rotate: sTable.rotate,
                                color: sTable.order != null
                                    ? Colors.green
                                    : Colors.grey,
                                seats: sTable.seats,
                               
                                
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                          .toList()),
                ),
```

LayoutWidget:

```
class LayoutWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  late  double width;
  late  double height;
  late double left;
  late  double top;


  LayoutWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.width,
    required this.height,
    required this.left,
    required this.top,
   
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _LayoutWidgetState();
}

class _LayoutWidgetState extends State<LayoutWidget> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        RotationTransition(
          turns: widget.type == 0
              ? const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(0)
              : AlwaysStoppedAnimation(rotationValue / 360),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onPanUpdate: (details) {
              widget.top =  widget.top+ details.delta.dy;
              widget.left =  widget.left+ details.delta.dx;

              setState(() {

              });
            },
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                showMenu = !showMenu;
              });
            },
            child: myWidget()
}
```

Can anyone help why i am unable to drag on screen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you you can get Idea from this code. In this code you can drag Container anywhere in the Screen and set it. And also check this [Gesture Detector Overview](https://medium.com/litslink/flutter-gesturedetector-86fc937aaf17) for Gesture Detector detail.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GestureDetectorPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      color: Colors.grey[100],
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      child: MainContent(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainContent extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_MainContentState createState() => _MainContentState();
}

class _MainContentState extends State<MainContent> {
  GlobalKey key = GlobalKey();

  String dragDirection = '';
  String startDXPoint = '50';
  String startDYPoint = '50';
  String dXPoint;
  String dYPoint;
  String velocity;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
       onHorizontalDragStart: _onHorizontalDragStartHandler,
       onVerticalDragStart: _onVerticalDragStartHandler,
       onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onDragUpdateHandler,
       onVerticalDragUpdate: _onDragUpdateHandler,
       onHorizontalDragEnd: _onDragEnd,
       onVerticalDragEnd: _onDragEnd,
       dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.start, // default
       behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
       child: Stack(
         children: [
           Positioned(
             left: double.parse(this.startDXPoint),
             top: double.parse(this.startDYPoint),
             child: Container(
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
               color: Colors.green,
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)
             ),
             child: Center(
               child: Padding(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                   child: Text('Draggable', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),),
               ),
             ),
           )
         ),
       ],
     ),
   );
 }

void _onHorizontalDragStartHandler(DragStartDetails details) {
  setState(() {
    this.dragDirection = "HORIZONTAL";
    this.startDXPoint = '${details.globalPosition.dx.floorToDouble()}';
    this.startDYPoint = '${details.globalPosition.dy.floorToDouble()}';
  });
}

/// Track starting point of a vertical gesture
void _onVerticalDragStartHandler(DragStartDetails details) {
  setState(() {
    this.dragDirection = "VERTICAL";
    this.startDXPoint = '${details.globalPosition.dx.floorToDouble()}';
    this.startDYPoint = '${details.globalPosition.dy.floorToDouble()}';
 });
}

void _onDragUpdateHandler(DragUpdateDetails details) {
  setState(() {
    this.dragDirection = "UPDATING";
    this.startDXPoint = '${details.globalPosition.dx.floorToDouble()}';
    this.startDYPoint = '${details.globalPosition.dy.floorToDouble()}';
  });
}

/// Track current point of a gesture
void _onHorizontalDragUpdateHandler(DragUpdateDetails details) {
  setState(() {
    this.dragDirection = "HORIZONTAL UPDATING";
    this.dXPoint = '${details.globalPosition.dx.floorToDouble()}';
    this.dYPoint = '${details.globalPosition.dy.floorToDouble()}';
    this.velocity = '';
  });
}

/// Track current point of a gesture
void _onVerticalDragUpdateHandler(DragUpdateDetails details) {
  setState(() {
    this.dragDirection = "VERTICAL UPDATING";
    this.dXPoint = '${details.globalPosition.dx.floorToDouble()}';
    this.dYPoint = '${details.globalPosition.dy.floorToDouble()}';
    this.velocity = '';
  });
}

/// What should be done at the end of the gesture ?
void _onDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
  double result = details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx.abs().floorToDouble();
  setState(() {
    this.velocity = '$result';
  });
 }

}
```

Comment: Hussian I tried this code and when I want to apply scale gesture to the same code it was not working. getting this error......Simultaneously having a vertical drag gesture recognizer, a horizontal drag gesture recognizer, and a scale gesture recognizer will result in the scale gesture recognizer being ignored, since the other two will catch all drags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Draggable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html) widget instead. Please try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int acceptedData = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        Draggable<int>(
          // Data is the value this Draggable stores.
          data: 10,
          feedback: Container(
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            child: const Icon(Icons.directions_run),
          ),
          childWhenDragging: Container(
            height: 100.0,
            width: 100.0,
            color: Colors.pinkAccent,
            child: const Center(
              child: Text('Child When Dragging'),
            ),
          ),
          child: Container(
            height: 100.0,
            width: 100.0,
            color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
            child: const Center(
              child: Text('Draggable'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        DragTarget<int>(
          builder: (
            BuildContext context,
            List<dynamic> accepted,
            List<dynamic> rejected,
          ) {
            return Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100.0,
              color: Colors.cyan,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Value is updated to: $acceptedData'),
              ),
            );
          },
          onAccept: (int data) {
            setState(() {
              acceptedData += data;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```